# Height/Radius ratio of a tank that is cylindrical with hemispherical ends, minimize cost of tank

Tags: calculus, optimization

Construct a tank with $2$ hemispherical ends attached to a cylinder. If the cost of making the hemispherical ends is twice as much as the cost of making the cylinder, find the ratio of $h$ to $R$ that minimizes the cost of the tank.

So far, I have calculated the equation for volume:
$V = ^2h + \frac{4}{3}r^3$

I am confused where to go next, I know there is a question involving a cylinder that has flat ends, but is not helpful.

Comment: Presumably when they say the ends are twice as expensive as the cylinder that is per area.  You need to write an equation for the cost of the tank based on the surface areas as a function of $r$ and $h$.  Your volume equation is missing a factor $h$ in the first term on the right.  Solve the volume equation for one of the variables, then plug that into the cost equation to get cost as a function of one variable.  Then take the derivative,set to zero...

Answer (score 1):

Let the ratio be $a$. The volume is

$$V = \pi r^2h+\frac43\pi r^3=\pi r^3(a+\frac43)$$

and the cost is,

$$ C =2\pi rh + 2\cdot 4\pi r^2= 2\pi r^2 (a+4)$$

Substitute $r$ with the volume equation to get

$$C= 2\pi \left(\frac V\pi \right )^{2/3} 
\frac {a+4}{\left( a+\frac43\right)^{2/3}}$$

Set $\frac {dC}{da} =0$,

$$\frac {1}{\left( a+\frac43\right)^{2/3}}
-\frac23 \frac {a+4}{\left( a+\frac43\right)^{5/3}}=0$$

to obtain the optimal ratio $a=4$.

Comment: @te4gan - no problem. You’re welcome